# Quick simple product creation autogenerate title for both store view?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product

Is there any way to make **auto create the name of the simple products when using the quick create feature** for both store view?

Answer (score 1):

By default in Magento 1.9, there is a **Autogenerate** checkbox when you create the simple associated products via the quick creation.

[image]

If you check that box, the name of the simple product will be based on the attribute you selected.

Example:

- your simple product has a black color and the parent product is called "Test"
- your simple product will be called "Test-black"

Example 2:

- your simple product has a black color and has a size of 6
- it will be called "Test-black-6" or "Test-6-black" depending on the order of your attributes